# gradle error :SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, nativescript

When i run gradle in my terminal, this shows up.
How can i resolve this dependency in gradle?

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
  at org.gradle.api.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:57)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:253)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Have you ever clicked that link?

Comment: yep solved it. seems in ubuntu you have to update the local gradle instead of the global one to avoid errors.